# tqdm Runs with no time(number) and a question mark

Tags: python, tqdm

100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

I can't display numbers. How do I fix it

tqdm Runs with no time(number) and a question mark..

```
start = time.time()
finish = time.time()
print(finish - start)
```

I did this and it didn't work

Comment: Plz elaborate your question. What's your intended input/output? What have you tried?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)